# how to use document.getElementById in jquery plug in so that it can take the id of the object which is using the plugin currently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on a jQuery plugin. I need to use `document.getElementById('somid');`The code is working if I use some id(suppose id of a particular text area). But as its a plugin I can not give an specific id because the plug in should be made like that it(the plug in) should work with any text area with which it is connected.
My html

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.myplugin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="source" id="src1" cols="150" rows="20" class="calling"></textarea>
<textarea name="source" id="src2" cols="150" rows="20" class="calling"></textarea>
</body>
```

my jquery.myplugin.js plugin

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.calling').keyup(function(e) {
$(this).requiredMethod(e.keyCode);
});});

 //My plugin

(function($) {


$.fn.requiredMethod = function(keyCode) {
      return this.each(function() { 

        var $this = $(this); 
        var previndex = 0;      
        var ctl = document.getElementById('src1'); //This is where the problem is
        var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd-1;
        var str = $this.val();

        //My code goes here where i use previndex,endPos ans str

        });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

My plug in is working for text area with `id="src1"`. But this plugin should work with all text areas with `class="calling"`. So what should be the code to do so ,so that I can get the `var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd-1;` for the text area I am working currently? 
I used the code `var ctl = document.getElementByClassName('reverie');` but its not working.
If anyone have not understand the problem please let me know,I will try to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use id here. `this` inside the `each` handler refer to the current dom element so you can either use `this` instead of `ctl` or can assign `this` to `ctl` like `var ctl = this`

```
(function ($) {


    $.fn.requiredMethod = function (keyCode) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var previndex = 0;
            var ctl = this //This is where the problem is
            var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd - 1;
            var str = $this.val();
            //My code goes here where i use previndex,endPos ans str

        });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.myplugin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="source" id="src1" cols="150" rows="20" class="calling"></textarea>
<textarea name="source" id="src2" cols="150" rows="20" class="calling"></textarea>
</body>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.calling').keyup(function(e) {
$(this).requiredMethod(e.keyCode);
});});

 //My plugin

(function($) {


$.fn.requiredMethod = function(keyCode) {
      return this.each(function() { 

        var $this = $(this); 
        var previndex = 0;      
        var ctl = this; //This is where the problem is
        var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd-1;
        var str = $this.val();

        //My code goes here where i use previndex,endPos ans str

        });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using document.getElementById

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.calling').keyup(function(e) {
$(this).requiredMethod(e.keyCode);
});});

 //My plugin

    (function ($) {


        $.fn.requiredMethod = function (keyCode) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var previndex = 0;
                var ctl = document.getElementById($this.attr("id"));
                var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd-1;
                var str =ctl.value;
                //My code goes here where i use previndex,endPos ans str

            });

        };

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: You have `this` and `$this`. To use document.getElementById when you have TWO pointers to the object is a plain waste of resources. `var ctl = document.getElementById($this.attr("id"));
                var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd-1;
var str =ctl.value;` can be written `var endPos = this.selectionEnd-1; var str = this.value;`